# Python: How to write this code from python shell into a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's happening here is that the first and second element of every tuple are getting multiplied, and it adds all of the products in the end. I know how to enter it in the Python shell, but how do I write it out as a function? Thanks for the help.

```
>>> x = [(70.9, 1, 24.8),
         (15.4, 2, 70.5),
         (30.0, 3, 34.6),
         (25.0, 4, 68.4),
         (45.00, 5, 99.0)]

>>> result = (a[0]*a[1] for a in x)
>>> sum(result)
>>> 516.7
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into how to define functions in python? I wouldn't recommend you do it in a python shell.

Comment: You can turn any expression statement into a function by adding `def make_result(x):` before it and `return result` after it. Or you can turn any whole suite of statements into a function by just adding `def do_stuff():` before them. Whether either of those gives you what you want depends on what exactly you wanted the function to do.

Comment: you can write a generator expression but you don't know how to define a function???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the function:

```
def my_func(x):
    result = (a[0]*a[1] for a in x)
    return sum(result)
```

Call the function:

```
x = [(70.9, 1, 24.8),
         (15.4, 2, 70.5),
         (30.0, 3, 34.6),
         (25.0, 4, 68.4),
         (45.00, 5, 99.0)]
my_func(x)
```

Result will be 516.7

Answer (score 0):

using numpy packege dot product also we can archive this easily

```
import numpy as np

x = [(70.9, 1, 24.8),(15.4, 2, 70.5),(30.0, 3, 34.6),(25.0, 4, 68.4),(45.00, 5, 99.0)]
def func(list):
   nmpyArray = np.array(list)

   mul = np.dot(nmpyArray[:, 0], nmpyArray[:, 1])

   print(mul)
   return mul

func(x)
```